# Struts2 Upload File ie

Tags: java, jsp, internet-explorer, struts2

In my struts2 application I am using “File Upload Interceptor” but internet explorer does not work. In firefox itself, and also chrome

```
<s:file name="upload" id="upload" />

<action name="GuardarAdjunto" class = "ArchivosAdjuntos" method="guardar">

       <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">
            text/plain,
            application/pdf,
            application/word,
            application/msword,             
            application/vnd.ms-excel,
            application/msexcel,
            application/x-msexcel,
            application/x-ms-excel,
            application/x-excel,
            application/x-dos_ms_excel,
            application/xls,
            application/x-xls,
            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
         </param>
         <param name="maximumSize">2000000</param>
        <param name="allowedExtensions">pdf,xls,doc,docx,xlsx,txt</param>
    </interceptor-ref>              
       <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/> 
    <result name="input">adjuntos.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">adjuntos.jsp</result>                      
    <result type="chain">
        <param name="actionName">ArchivosAdjuntos_</param>
        <param name="namespace">/contratos/plantilla</param>
    </result>         
</action>
```

Why not work on internet explorer?
Any solution?

Comment: because ie is ... nevermind. well which ire version are you using?

Comment: 1) It works in IE too. Define "not working", and show your code to be helped; 2) Your allowedTypes list is partial, there are probably other MIME you should include to enclose all the possible XLS and DOC

Comment: I do not work in IE. No work is nothing to do, I try to attach and does nothing.
I tried to remove the list of allowedtypes and still not working

Comment: Post your complete JSP where you use `<s:file>` tag.

Comment: <s:form id="f_adjuntos" name="f_adjuntos" action="contratos/plantilla/GuardarAdjunto" namespace="/" method="post" theme="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="if_adjuntos">
<s:file name="upload" id="upload" />
</s:form>